# How to set a css class for a yet to be display node?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.tree

I am using a Dijit Tree, and I need to change the CSS style for a node based on its item property.

The following code fails if the node has not been displayed yet (i.e. node is undefined) :

```
var node = this.tree.getNodesByItem(item);
if (node[0]) {
  domClass.toggle(node[0].domNode, className, add);
}
```

Is there any event that tells if a node is being displayed/has been created ?

Comment: Check first that `node` is not undefined?

Answer (score 0):

If `node` is `undefined` when not yet displayed, that variable should be [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and thus a simple logical AND (`&&`) guard within your `if`-statement should suffice:

```
var node = this.tree.getNodesByItem(item);
if (node && node[0]) {
  domClass.toggle(node[0].domNode, className, add);
}
```

Comment: What I meant was how can I get a notification that the node is displayed so I can call `domClass.toggle(node[0].domNode, className, add);`

Comment: I believe `Tree.getLabelClass(item) should do the job`